# React useMemo or useEffect called too many times on redux state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

I am trying different patterns on a new React application, In this case I have a redux store which contains a projects array of objects.
When the component loads I dispatch a new action which gets all the projects and set the store with the new values, in this case the list is rendered correctly.
When I dispatch the same actions from a children of the same component, the redux state is updated, the main component is rerendered but the list remain the same.

```
export const ProjectList: React.FC = () => {
//When projects change the component should rerender with the new store
  const { projects, isLoading, errors } = useSelector((store: IAppState) => store.projectState);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { setActiveProject } = useActiveProjectValue();
  const { setIsNewTask } = useIsNewTaskValue();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('called');
    dispatch(getProjectsAction());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="ProjectList">
      {!isLoading ? (
        projects.map((project: IProject) => (
          <ProjectListItem
            key={project.docId ? project.projectId : uuid()}
            handleClick={() => handleClick(project)}
            project={project}
          >
            {project.name}
          </ProjectListItem>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>Loading projects</p>
      )}
      {errors && <p>{errors}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have also tried to change useEffect with useMemo and add a project dependency to this function, in this case it works but it seems to trigger the action too many times:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProjectsAction());
  }, [projects]);
```

Any advice/solution?
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're mutating the array in the reducer. Can you post your action creator and reducer?

Comment: turned out I was using an async func synchronously, it was a my mistake, thanks anyway